# AWS API Gateway and NLB integration

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to integrate AWS API Gateway with the AWS NLB. I am building an microservices architecture project in which I have around 20 microservices which I want to be load balanced through NLB and deploy all the microservices to ECS fargate.

Now the problem is whenever I am trying to integrate the AWS NLB to AWS Api gateway I need to add every api in the aws api gateway.

But what I want is Make VPC for AWS NLB in api gateway and just make one api and my all api's can be router through that api only. For example if I have 1000 API's I need to add all of them insided my api gateway.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are these microservices HTTP? If so you should use the ALB with host/path routing.  You should be able to make a base proxy integration that passes all calls through it.  That will work for the NLB or the ALB

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html

Comment: Hi BoostChicken, Thanks for the solution. But I am using spring boot application for my microservices architecture.  To deploy these spring boot microservices I am using AWS ECS fargate. But the issue is while integrating AWS NLB with the api gateway I need to add every api that I need to call. So is there is a way I just add my NLB to the api gateway and route all request through api gateway with single integration of NLB.